# Why when I click on the next page the button edit or delete is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is my script. I can edit and delete on the first page, but when I click on next page edit and delete are not working. What seems to be the problem?

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('.edit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#edit').modal('show');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        getRow(id);
      });

      $('.delete').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#delete').modal('show');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        getRow(id);
      });
    });

   function getRow(id){
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'attendance_row.php',
        data: {id:id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
        $('#datepicker_edit').val(response.date);
        $('#attendance_date').html(response.date);
        $('#edit_time_in').val(response.time_in);
        $('#edit_time_out').val(response.time_out);
        $('#attid').val(response.attid);
        $('#employee_name').html(response.firstname+' '+response.lastname);
        $('#del_attid').val(response.attid);
        $('#del_employee_name').html(response.firstname+' '+response.lastname);
        }
    });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you the same script in both pages?

Comment: yes, both pages has the same scripts.

Comment: just to make sure , got to the second page and press `ctrl + u` to see the source page and see if the script is there as well.

Comment: What do you mean by `edit and delete are not working`? Are the `click()` handlers firing? If so, are the modals showing? Is the ajax request getting sent? None of the above?

Comment: When I go to page, I can edit and delete the first 10 data but once I click on the next button to view the other data, and click either edit or delete. the button doesn't work

Comment: @bonbon Is this really a php/html question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous.

Before the elements are appended via ajax, the click handler gets registered, which find no elements with $(".edit").

You should probably use `event delegation`.
Try to change your function:

```
$(function(){
      $('.edit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#edit').modal('show');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        getRow(id);
      });

      $('.delete').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#delete').modal('show');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        getRow(id);
      });
    });
```

To this:

```
$(function(){
      $(document).on('click','.edit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#edit').modal('show');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        getRow(id);
      });

      $(document).on('click','.delete',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#delete').modal('show');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        getRow(id);
      });
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this helps, thank you very much, can you explain further?

Comment: Do not forget to mark as answered and vote it up :)